# Insert a delay in Processing sketch

Tags: drawing, processing

I am attempting to insert a delay in `Processing` sketch. I tried `Thread.sleep()` but I guess it will not work because, as in Java, it prevents rendering of the drawings.

Basically, I have to draw a triangle with delays in drawing three sides.

**How do I do that?**

Answer (score 3):

> Processing programs can read the value of computer’s clock. The current second is read with the **second()** function, which returns values from 0 to 59. The current minute is read with the **minute()** function, which also returns values from 0 to 59. *- [Processing: A Programming Handbook](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/processing)*

Other clock related functions : **millis()**, **day()**, **month()**, **year()**.

Those numbers can be used to trigger events and calculate the passage of time, as in the following Processing sketch quoted from the aforementioned book:

```
// Uses millis() to start a line in motion three seconds 
// after the program starts

int x = 0;

void setup() { 
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  if (millis() > 3000) {
    x++;
    line(x, 0, x, 100);
  }
}
```

Here's an example of a triangle whose sides are drawn each one after 3 seconds (the triangle is reset every minute):

```
int i = second();

void draw () {
  background(255);
  beginShape();
  if (second()-i>=3) {
    vertex(50,0);
    vertex(99,99);
  }
  if (second()-i>=6) vertex(0,99);
  if (second()-i>=9) vertex(50,0);
  endShape();
}
```

Comment: My program runs out of `draw()`. It is blank

Answer (score 2):

As @user2468700 suggests, use a time keeping function. I like [millis()](http://processing.org/reference/millis_.html).

If you have a value to keep track of the time at certain intervals and the current time (continuously updated) you can check if one timer(manually updated one) falls behind the other(continuous one) based on a delay/wait value. If it does, update your data (number of points to draw in this case) and finally the local stop-watch like value.

Here's a basic commented example.
Rendering is separated from data updates to make it easier to understand.

```
//render related
PVector[] points = new PVector[]{new PVector(10,10),//a list of points
                                 new PVector(90,10),
                                 new PVector(90,90)};
int pointsToDraw = 0;//the number of points to draw on the screen
//time keeping related
int now;//keeps track of time only when we update, not continuously
int wait = 1000;//a delay value to check against

void setup(){
  now = millis();//update the 'stop-watch'
}
void draw(){
  //update
  if(millis()-now >= wait){//if the difference between the last 'stop-watch' update and the current time in millis is greater than the wait time
    if(pointsToDraw < points.length) pointsToDraw++;//if there are points to render, increment that
    now = millis();//update the 'stop-watch'
  }
  //render
  background(255);
  beginShape();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < pointsToDraw; i++) {
    vertex(points[i].x,points[i].y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```